# How add note on write in a row in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Hiho i tried to get how open a new note when a write in a row.

In my googlespreadsheet i have 10 columns (column U to AT) on i write things. When i add a new data in a empty row, i need that when i finish of put of data, then there will be open a box note for write it.

I found the next code that is useful on edit, but i need one time insert the data not in edit.

```
    function onEdit() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
cell.setComment(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an IF statement to check if that last row is "Complete" columns U to UT have a value

find the last row in column U thanks to SO user moogsdad

```
var Uvals = ss.getRange("U1:U").getValues();
var Ulast = Uvals.filter(String).length;
```

try this code below.  I've not tested it so it may have a missing semi-colon or curly bracket somewhere.

```
function onEdit() {

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  // get last row on column U
  var Uvals = sheet.getRange("U1:U").getValues();
  var Ulast = Uvals.filter(String).length;

  // check is the row being edited matches the last row
  if (cell.getRow() == Ulast) {

    var updateRange = sheet.getRange("U"+Ulast+":AT"+Ulast);
    var UpdateValues = range.getValues();
    var isComplete = true;

    // should loop through all cells in you update range and set isComplete to false is any are blank.
    for (var row in UpdateValues ) {
     for (var col in UpdateValues[row]) {
       if (UpdateValues[row][col] == '') {
          isComplete = false;
       }
     }

     // if all cells complete then set comment
     if (isComplete == true) {
       cell.setComment(" ");
     }

  } // end if edited row matches last row in U

} // end of function
```